# time dependent emails not getting sent to the user?

Tags: force.com, workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a workflow rule, and when it's met, a time depenant workflow action is fired to send an email. I see the email in the email in the `Time-Based Workflow`section, and it sits there and disappears. the email never gets sent to the user.

This is all in my sandbox, and I'm just testing it before I move it over to QA.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times in a sandbox, you need to modify your email settings.  By default it is set to 'System Email Only'.

Check your email Deliverability by going to **Setup** -> **Email Administration** -> **Deliverability**

Then make sure it is set to '**All Email**'

Hope this helps

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=emailadmin_deliverability.htm&siteLang=en_US

The System email only setting is especially useful for controlling email sent from sandboxes so that testing and development work doesn’t send test emails to your users.
Newly created sandboxes default to System email only.
Sandboxes created before ’Spring 13 default to All email.

Comment: ah, as of the spring 13 release they changed it from  all main to system mail for email alerts.

Comment: Yes they did, tripped me up for a while as well

Answer (score 0):

Never gets sent? or Never gets delivered? or The user never finds it?

Sadly, those aren't the same question.

Dunc44 is right on for checking *sent*

If it's being sent, you'll need to do some investigation to determine if you're receiving it. Sometimes, Salesforce mail deliverability isn't brilliant. Your upstream ISP may be blocking the email for one of ... at least dozens of reasons. Additionally, if it is being delivered, you may find it was put inside the deepest darkest regions of your spam folder.

Comment: Great point, I was only considering if it was not being sent at all.

Comment: that is a great point. @Dunc44 suggestion worked, but that is a good thing to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the system debugs of workflow. By default a sandbox don't authorised to send email to users. You should get following error in your debug logs:

> First exception on row 0; first error: NO_MASS_MAIL_PERMISSION

Also write your email code in `try-catch` block

```
try
{
  SendEmailResult[] results = connection.sendEmail(messages);
}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
  System.debug(ex.getMessage()); // 
}
```